# How to extract substring from string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

So I was just wondering how I would extract `http://www.google.com` from the following string:

```
<div class="asdf"><a href="http://www.google.com">
```

Let's say I had a huge string with a bunch of links in there, and I wanted to extract all of the links within the a `href`'s quotation marks, how would I do that?

Comment: You should use `regex` or `BeautifulSoup`  to do that.

Comment: I think he already wanted that, judging by the `regex` tag.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 good call, I didn't read the tags.

Comment: Which regex is it that matches any number of characters? Let's say I want to find all of them, it would be str.findall('a href="http://RegExHere"'). I want to match all finds for 'a href="http://...." '

Answer (score 2):

[You need an HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.select("div.asdf > a[href]"):
    print(link["href"])
```

This would match all the links having `href` attribute located directly inside the `div` element having "asdf" class.

You can also just find all the `a` elements in the input document:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    print(link["href"])
```

Or:

```
for link in soup.select("a[href]"):
    print(link["href"])
```

Comment: But what if there are multiple divs? It would be one huge string with a ton of divs that contain an a[href].

Comment: @Matt I've updated the answer and added some more generic information. Though it would be good to see your real input and the desired output.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'm currently using Scrapy's xpaths. So I think it might be response.xpath("//div.asdf/a/@href").extract() then?? Sorry, I'm not sure if you're familiar with xpaths.

Comment: @Matt in case of Scrapy, you can do it with `response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'asdf')]/a/@href").extract()` or a CSS selector: `response.css("div.asdf > a::attr(href)").extract()`.

Comment: The only problem is, there are multiple listings by day in the entire response, so I only want to parse through the first day. Hence why I split the body and only deal with the first portion (the one that contains today's date). Once I get today's portion, that is when I want to parse for links. Parsing through ALL of the response's links takes forever.

Comment: Alex, see my most recent comment. That is what we currently do, and it takes forever to parse through the ENTIRE page's divs. I only want the divs for a certain section, but I don't know how to do that without turning it into a string after splitting.

Comment: @Matt as I've mentioned previously, it's difficult to tell how to help without seeing your actual html and the desired result.